# Excel Corruption Diagnostic Resources\ Tools

Tags: excel, vba

I have an office 365\ excel app using vba\ ado\ custom ui ribbon\ xml.

I have been seeing corruption from time to time but cant pinpoint the cause-- and only become aware of it with some testing of the saved workbook.

I am going to accept that corruption occurs for whatever reason-- and perhaps that would be another thread.

My question is-- are there resources\ utilities out there that would allow one to determine if a workbook is corrupted-- versus a full regression test with every set of changes (save).

Comment: Note that asking for tools is off-topic according [ask]. But what I noticed is that the Format `xlsm/xlsx` can eaisly corrupt. I had a lot of corruptions with bigger files and the use of VBA, and I never found out what actually the cause of the issues was. Once a file is corrupted it usually stays corrupted (even if Excel said it repaired it). The only way out is starting a new file from scratch and copy over the data (best without copying formattings). • I recommend you to try the binary `xlsb` files they are much more stabele and I never had corruption here! The are even smaller files.

Comment: Thanks so much. Would you happen to know of any resources\ utilities I can use to identify if a workbook is corrupted?

Comment: As I said asking for tools and off-site resources is off-topic. Since even Microsoft Office somtimes cannot determine properly if a file is corrupt or not, I doubt that anyone else can. Somtimes Office tells you the file was corrupt and tries to repair it, but it looks like this is just gambling because it might just work or not. Sometimes a file is obviously corrupt and Office dosen't see it. Once a file is suspicious to be corrupt the only way to be sure is start a new one. Actually I never had a corrupt `xslb` file but many `xlsm/xlsx` files.